# how to backup my firebase datase to another server, in cloud server hosting or VPS server

Tags: firebase, server, cron, database-backups

I have an application on firebase, but I must have server backup on another server, in cloud hosting or VPS, Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Both Firebase Realtime Database and Firestore offer backup capability to a GCS bucket.

**Firebase Realtime Database:**

- Use the "Backups" tab on the console and use the wizard to configure the backup.  There's more about how to restore and how files are named [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/backups).  There is no additional cost for the backup operation, but you are obviously charged for the storage of the backups in GCS.

**For Firestore:**

- You can use the `gcloud firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]` command to export to a GCS bucket, either the entire database or just one collection.  Full documentation about restores, partial exports, etc, is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import).  Note you are charged for document reads to do the backup in addition to the GCS storage costs.
- There does not appear to be a built-in way to automate this but the Admin SDK includes a [`FirestoreAdminClient.exportDocuments`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/v1.FirestoreAdminClient.html#exportDocuments) (that link is for Node) call you could presumably use to call from a scheduled cloud function to do the work.

You must be on the Blaze (pay as you go) plan for both databases.